# If record is not found in the database, should I return a 404?

Tags: seo

I have pages with structure like this some_page?id=123

Sometimes records are deleted, but those pages still get visited by people and search engines.  One problem is that I have a php script and no MVC structure, so I have to query the DB all on the same page before I find out that the user record does not exist.

Should I return a 404 in that case? Or what is best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, 404 sounds like a good fit.

Comment: Besides the standards and developer best practices, you should also consider SEO impacts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the client (users, search engines, etc.) requests a resource that does not exist and has **never existed**, a 404 status ("Not Found") should be returned.

However, if a resource is requested that **once existed** and has since been permanently removed, a 410 status ("Gone") should be returned.  A 410 status specifically states that the resource will never be available in the future, and triggers search engines to remove that page from their indexes.

A 301 status is used if a resource's location has changed permanently.

Comment: thanks - my issue is that also the fact that the resource is not found is discovered in the middle of script execution. If I return 410 from the middle of the script - will that still be effective?

Comment: +1. You should only do that however, when you know that the missing resource has in fact once existed, for example if the database still has the record with a "deleted flag" set.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where in the script this is implemented, so long as (in your case) a 410 status header is returned **at some point**.

Comment: N.B. If your page IDs are generated sequentially, it should be simple to decide whether or not a resource ever existed, and therefore whether to return 404 or 410.

Answer (score 5):

A 404 is when something is not found and since the resource being looked up is not found, it seems entirely appropriate to me.

Comment: is it still ok to return 404 when you are half-way down in a script?  How does it get enterpreted by search engines?

Comment: It does not matter how far down in your script you are, but if it has already produced output (you should defer that until you know if the record exists). You can only set the content-type when you have not yet send any data to the browser. If that is the case, you can throw away all previous output and make a nice 404 page. If not (i.e. you already started sending a normal page), then you cannot change the already committed 200.

Answer (score 1):

That depends if you want to keep the user on your site. If you redirect permanently to another page, then make sure you also have a 301 in the headers so that search engines don't penalize you for to many links pointing to the same page.

A 404 is ok, but you will get bounces from that page if users' browsers don't render any content.

I personally think the best approach is show a friendly page for users and set headers correctly for search engines.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

yes. that would be proper provided you have no substitute to capitalize with. it would be better for you to server up a similarly subjected resource or even a re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but don't forget to offer the visitor some additional related content. Just because the url isn't found doesn't mean that the visitor should be ignored. 
Show a custom 404 page with some other sections of the site that may pertain - possibly the most visited pages,...